# RXJS Emit array item on event trigger

Tags: rxjs

Using RxJS Id like to emit each array item on an event/click.

I have below which works fine, but is there a cleaner way?

```
const testEventClick = new Subject();
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
from(array)
.pipe(
  concatMap(val => {
    return new Observable(sub => {
      testEventClick.subscribe(x => {
        sub.next(val);
        sub.complete();
      });
    });
  })
)
.subscribe(console.log);
testEventClick.next();
testEventClick.next();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the other way around and observe the subject.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-l4ttzh

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Moxxi - i ended up finding the zip operator useful here